# Android WebView is blank after going to another Activity and then back

Tags: android, webview

I used a `WebView` to load a `url` successfully, sometimes when I switch to another page and return it become blank, only when I kill the application and restart it the `WebView` will load `url` normally.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I am facing this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the webview in the onStart method instead of where I assume you are loading in the onCreate.

Check out this documentation to see the activity life cycle.  It may help.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Thanks,i do loading in a Fragment and t try to load in method onStart(),bu it does`t     work